# import data directly from Elasticsearch index to h2o

Tags: elasticsearch, h2o, h2o4gpu

Is there anyway to import data directly from Elasticsearch index  to h2o through any api.

Thanks
Sarvendra

Answer (score 0):

H2O does not support importing data directly from Elasticsearch. You can write it to CSV and then import it to H2O. The file formats that are supported are: CSV (delimited) files, ORC, SVMLight, ARFF, XLS/XLSX, Avro, Parquet. Data sources that could be used are: Local or Remotes Files, S3, HDFS, JDBC, Hive. You can refer to the documentation on [Getting Data Into H2O](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/getting-data-into-h2o.html).

Comment: Kindly help to suggest on this...Elasticsearch is no sql database but it provides a sql jdbc driver using which any application can connect and import elasticsearch index table as wrapper sql table.Does h2o sql import support this ?



I am trying to import but only schema(columns ) are imported but no data is imported..